# Sending Json Array with Http Get in Android

Tags: android, web-services, http-get, arrays

iam calling a webservice(php http get request)

```
http://website.com/admin/employee_login.php?fun_name=abc&company_code=1&employee_ss=123&gtime=02:22 PM&x_id=350&v_id=9&task={"Walking":"1","Transfers":"1","OstomyCare":"1"}
```

but when am encoding this url am getting something different with %20 something like that, and it's not updating the tasks in the server database. Is there any method where i can pass parameters as a json array without encoding like same above ?

thank you

Comment: why don't you try some HTTP Post request? You can pass parameters and access by $_POST[] variable. And why do you want to send data as JSON?

Comment: y r u sending json in get? u can try post also

Answer (score 0):

Before sending the url and parameters are url encoded. For instance spaces become %20. On the receiving side php should url decode the parameters. There is a php function which does that for you. After that you have the original parameters back.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
String value = "my url value"; // put here your url

URLEncoder.encode(value,"UTF-8")
```

Comment: Could you please add some explanation to your code?